# Is it really impossible to use the resolved value of a Promise outside its own scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, localforage

I'm using localforage in a custom React hook that is meant to cache and return data. If data already exists, return it. If data doesn't exist, cache it and then return it. Before I was using a synchronous LRU library, but it seems the asynchronous nature of IndexedDB makes this a lot harder.

As of now, the custom hook is returning a promise with a resolved value that I need access to in one of my components. The data is right there, and yet I can't get to it. I've tried a mix of async/await, generators, and SE threads, but I suppose I'll use this snippet to post with.

Here's a condensed version of the component receiving the promise from the custom hook

```js
const Component = ({ match }) => {
    let data = useSuspenseFetch(match.params.id)
        .then(res => {
            console.log('need this', res)
            return res
        })
    console.log('right here', data)

    return <></>
}

export default Component
```

Is there any way to achieve this?
I feel like I've gotten so close so many times, but there's always some pitfall.

Comment: You have to wait for the promise to resolve, either with async/await, or inside the .then. Store the return value in component state so that your component can use the value when you get the promise result back and set it in state

Comment: That's hilarious, I actually remember earlier having a mini epiphany and realizing this exact solution, but was so focused on trying to return actual data instead of a promise in the hook that I didn't get around to it in time before my brain had died. I haven't tested this yet, but you're totally correct. Thank you for pointing out my stupidity. I'll prolly have to throw it in a useEffect so it doesn't get re-rendered, but should be cake. *should*.. :)